# GeoServer pregeneralized layers not working as expected

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, generalization

I've set up GeoServer 2.1.4 and installed the feature-pregeneralized-2.1.4.jar plug in and processed my shape files into each of their separate folders with the generalized shapefiles and I've check these and they are correct.

I've followed the tutorial and set up the shapefiles and configured the XML file as per the article, but I'm not getting the expected log file entries.  I'm getting the fact that the datastores are getting loaded from each of the shapefiles, but when I do a layer preview I don't get the switching between the different shapefiles.

Below is the geninfo_shapefile.xml that I have sitting in the root with the folders:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <GeneralizationInfos version="1.0">
        <GeneralizationInfo dataSourceName="file:data/Local_Authority/0/LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012.shp"  featureName="LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012" baseFeatureName="LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012" geomPropertyName="the_geom">
            <Generalization dataSourceName="file:data/Local_Authority/1.0/LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012.shp"  distance="1" featureName="LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012" geomPropertyName="the_geom"/>
            <Generalization dataSourceName="file:data/Local_Authority/2.5/LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012.shp"  distance="2.5" featureName="LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012" geomPropertyName="the_geom"/>
            <Generalization dataSourceName="file:data/Local_Authority/5.0/LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012.shp"  distance="5" featureName="LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012" geomPropertyName="the_geom"/>
            <Generalization dataSourceName="file:data/Local_Authority/25.0/LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012.shp"  distance="25" featureName="LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012" geomPropertyName="the_geom"/>
            <Generalization dataSourceName="file:data/Local_Authority/100.0/LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012.shp"  distance="100" featureName="LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012" geomPropertyName="the_geom"/>
            <Generalization dataSourceName="file:data/Local_Authority/500.0/LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012.shp"  distance="500" featureName="LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012" geomPropertyName="the_geom"/>
            <Generalization dataSourceName="file:data/Local_Authority/1500.0/LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012.shp"  distance="1500" featureName="LocalAuthority_OSBL_May2012" geomPropertyName="the_geom"/>
        </GeneralizationInfo>
    </GeneralizationInfos>
```

When I go to map preview and then check the log I only have:

```
2012-10-17 17:50:33,961 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2012-10-17 17:50:33,961 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    blah
    blah
    blah
```

Can anyone assist me with this?

Comment: did you try the GeoServer users forum? http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/GeoServer-User-f3786390.html It's very helpful and you'll often get feedback from the developers themselves. They might start by suggesting you move to 2.2, now stable.

Comment: I agree about asking on the user mailing list. The developer of that module does not seem to be looking at Stackexchange but he's normally helpful on the mailinsg list.

Comment: 2.1.4 is so old there is no chance of getting an answer any more